# Firefox Extension: New Tab Shortcuts per Container?

Tags: firefox, icons, browser-tabs, multi-account-containers

I can pin shortcut icons on the new tab page.  Has anyone found a Firefox extension that displays pinned icons based on the container chosen?  e.g. The new tab page icons for the banking container would be different from the new tab page icons for the media container.

The "find more add-ons" search not very helpful.